# Describing Homomorphisms....?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\Bbb Q$ be the additive group of rational numbers (i.e., the group whose elements are the set of rational numbers and whose operation is addition). Describe all the homomorphisms from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Q$.

*Basically, I understand the definition of a homomorphism. 
But I don't understand how to find homomorphisms from a group? Shouldn't it be infinite?*

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that a homomorphism of abelian groups $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is actually $\mathbb{Q}$-linear. Then, recall what $K$-linear maps $K \to V$ look like, where $V$ is any $K$-vector space and $K$ is a field. (Big hint: Look at the image of $1 \in K$.)